ArcGIS 106385 "Workspace or data source is read only" when using multiprocess to intersect a featureclass on a network drive
I use arcpy.analysis.Intersect to bring data (specific to my study area) housed on a network drive to my local machine for analysis. Sometimes the study areas are quite large, and so I break them up into smaller extents - each extent runs the analysis, and then the outputs are merged at the end. I do this using the multiprocessing module in python.
Within the past month, these workflows have been interrupted by ESRI's 106385 error. I have never seen this error before, and their explanation has not been helpful. It seems to only occur when I am doing parallel computations, such as this:
import os
import arcpy
import multiprocessing as mp


study_area = r"path/to/study_area.shp"
workspace = r"path/to/workspace"
data_file = r"path/to/analysis/data/on/network/drive"
n_processors = 5

fids = [i for i in range(0,20)] # FIDs of my hypothetical study area file
chunks = [fids[i:i + n_processors] for i in range(0, len(fids), n_processors)]
input_gdbs = list()
input_fcs = list()

# Create sub-areas
for n,c in enumerate(chunks):
    arcpy.management.CreateFileGDB(workspace, f"working_gdb_{n}")
    arcpy.conversion.FeatureClassToFeatureClass(study_area, working_gdb, f"sub_area_{n}", 
                                                where_clause=f"FID >={min(c)} AND FID <= {max(c)}")
    input_gdbs.append(os.path.join(workspace, f"working_gdb_{n}.gdb")
    input_fcs.append(os.path.join(workspace, f"working_gdb_{n}.gdb", f"sub_area_{n}")

inputs = [([input_fcs[i], data_file], os.path.join(input_gdbs, "analysis_data")) for i in range(0, len(input_fcs))]

pool = mp.Pool(n_processors)
results = pool.starmap(arcpy.analysis.Intersect, inputs)
pool.close()
pool.join()

Having multiple processes reading from the same featureclass simultaneously has until now not caused an issue.
Here are some solutions I found:

Not enough memory - checked, and I have lots of hard drive space and memory.
Insufficient permissions - checked, I have full admin control.
Dropbox (or OneDrive) is interfering - checked, that's not happening.
Need to reset your instance of ArcGIS - did this, resolved the error for about 24 hours, and then it recurred.

The only thing that seems to help right now is to copy the data on to my local machine and work with it from there. However that's not a permanent solution, since this data needs to live on the network, and it doesn't work all the time.
Has anyone else run into something like this, and maybe found a solution?

Concurrent read-write use of file geodatabase is not supported, nor is read-write use when the table already has a read lock. Network use of file geodatabase is consistently 50% of local use, so even read-only concurrent use on a file share is not recommended. Having multiple processes reading a file geodatabase concurrently has always been fraught. I suggest you follow best practice, and copy the data locally before read/write access.
